# Creating a hash table when dealing with big data

Tags: python, pyspark, multiprocessing, bigdata, ram

I have a text file which has 110,000,000 rows of passwords (2.5 gig).  The task is to come up with a hash function which creates minimum collisions. The file already has 10M duplicates(definition: similar passwords with similar hash values (AABB = BBAA)).

I have come up with this code but I am not able to run it. My computer has 8 gigabyte Ram.

This is my code:

```
data = 110000000
hash_table_size = int((30*data))/100)
hash_table = {i:[] for i in range(hash_table_size)}
with open('passwords2.txt') as file:
    sum_ = 0
    k = 3000
    index_ = 0
    for password in tqdm(file):
        password = ''.join(sorted(password))
        for character in password:
            ascii_value = ord(character) 
            sum_ += (ascii_value + k)*i
            index_ =  sum%hash_table_size
        hash_table[index_] = password
```

and this counts the number of collisions

```
length_ = 0
for i in range(hash_table_size):
    if len(hash_table[i]) !=1
       length_ += len(hash_table[i])
```

I tried to run this code in my pycharm on my windows but my system became so slow and I couldn't work with it anymore. I also tried running it on my ubuntu installed on a virtual machine with 4 gig Ram, again no response.

I don't know how to improve this code. My first strategy was using `with open() as file:` so I don't read everything into memory all at once. But later I need to create a hash_table and although I get only 30% of the rows as my size, again there will be ram issues. Is there any advice I could get?
I appreciate it.

P.s. I also tried it with pyspark. The map part works fine but the reduce part occupies all of my memory.

Comment: Can you share the pyspark code? This may be just the issue with the `reduce` function,